# when I define a percentage value for the height of the children with position absolute it works although there is no defined height to the parent

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

here I just styled the button I have no any problem

```css
button {
    background-color: rgb(21, 163, 92);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: block;
    margin: 150px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

here is my question because if I removed `position: absolute` it will not accept percentage height but with position absolute percentage height value is accepted

```css
button > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300%;
    height: 350%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;   
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
```

also here there is no problem I am just making the ripple button effect

```css
button:active > div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<html> 
    <body>
        button>click
            <div></div>
        </button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Well, actually what you state in your question title is exactly how it is supposed to work. Do you think you could rephrase your question?
See “If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly […] and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto” – [CSS height on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)